# Extract data in PDF in UIPath

Tags: function, pdf, split, extract, uipath

I am trying to exact some specific data from a PDF file Using IUPath.

The data in PDF looks like this :

**** hjeprj3 **** James Fish **** JDR0929879 **** jdloin2 B5339 ||

I need to exact the name "James Fish". 
It will always have the same format, always **** text **** first name last name **** text
And I will always have to extract the name, which will be different.

I used this function : 
PDFText.Substring(PDFText.IndexOf("**** ",0)+15,16) but as the name will always be diferent it doesn't return the correct value.

Can you kindly advise?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If your function is currently working for this name, but not other names, then I would suggest making your string longer. And then using the Strings.Split() function to delimit your string by the "*" character, only taking the first string using indexing, like this "(0)".

You can then use Strings.Trim() to remove any trailing spaces that might be left after the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@O.P. - Adapting your answer slightly to allow it to work with names of any length:

```
Strings.Trim(Strings.Split(PDFText.Substring(PDFText.IndexOf("**** ",0)+15,30),"*")(0))
```

Here I have changed the length of the substring from 16 to 30, which I imagine would be long enough for most names (adapt the length if you need to). This should return "James Fish **** JDR0929879 ***", or something similar if I've missed 1 or 2 characters.

The Strings.Split() function using "*" as the delimiter will then split this substring into several other substrings, of which we want the first one at index (0).

The Strings.Trim() function will then remove the extra space at the end of the surname. You could use RTrim() if you prefer as technically that is all that is required here. Trim() removes spaces from the start and the end, we only need to remove from the end here, but best to be careful with strings.

Comment: Hello, I tried but it didn't work. it returned something totally different ": 5001281960\r\n\r\nThis purchase" which I do not understand why. It seems like it doesn't recognize the "*" sign.

Comment: My bad, It is working, I have miswritten a variable. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the value within the 1 appearance of *** and the second. Being the substring function something like this

```
Substring (int startIndex, int length);
```

With indexOF you can take the start Index and you could achieve the length by doing 2nd Index position - 1st index position.

---

Or you can just split into array using the *** and take the second appareance in it. Check this links to achieve this solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/